# Integrating $\int^{\infty}_0\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}\text{ d}x$ using contour integration only

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

I have the integral $$I=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}\text{ d}x$$
for real $n>0$ that I want to evaluate *only* with contour integration.

(I already know the identity that $\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{x^{s-1}}{\exp(x)-1}\text{ d}x$)

---

I let $$f(z)=\frac{z^n}{e^z-1}$$ noting that there is a removable singularity at $0$, and poles every $z=2\pi im$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}, m\neq0$. As a result, I set up the following contour $\mathcal{C}$ shown below, where I would take the limit as $R\rightarrow+\infty$ and $\epsilon\rightarrow+0$.

[image]

By the Residue theorem, $$\oint_{\mathcal{C}}f(z)\text{ d}z=\int_{\text{Right}}+\int_{\text{Top}}+\int_{\text{Left}}+\int_{\text{Bottom}}+\int_rf(z)\text{ d}z=0$$

Parameterizing the integrals yields $$\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{(R+iy)^n}{e^R e^{iy}-1}i\text{ d}y + \int^{\epsilon}_{R}\frac{(2\pi i+x)^n}{e^{2\pi i}e^x-1}\text{ d}x + \int^{0}_{2\pi-\epsilon}\frac{(iy)^n}{e^{iy}-1}i\text{ d}y + \int^{R}_0\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}\text{ d}x + \int^{-\frac\pi 2}_{0}\frac{(2\pi i+\epsilon e^{i\theta})^n}{e^{2\pi i}e^{\epsilon e^{i\theta}}-1}i\epsilon e^{i\theta}\text{ d}\theta=0$$

Since $f(z)$ approaches $0$ as $\Re(z)$ becomes large, $\int_{\text{Right}}f(z)\text{ d}z=\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{(R+iy)^n}{e^r e^{iy}-1}i\text{ d}y$ should go to $0$. More rigorously, I moved the limit as $R\rightarrow +\infty$ inside (the function should uniformly converge I think so this is legal?) and indeed it would go to $0$.

$\int_{\text{Bottom}}f(z)\text{ d}z=I$ so we can ignore that for now. I'm thinking that we possibly could use a Laurent series for $\int_rf(z)\text{ d}z=\int^{-\frac\pi 2}_{0}\frac{(2\pi i+\epsilon e^{i\theta})^n}{e^{2\pi i}e^{\epsilon e^{i\theta}}-1}i\epsilon e^{i\theta}\text{ d}\theta$ since we're taking the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow +0$ but honestly I'm not sure how. If I directly take the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow +0$ of the integrand, Wolfram Alpha tells me it's equal to $(2\pi i)^n$, which would mean the entire integral is equal to $2^{n-1}(i\pi)^{n+1}$, but since it's such a complicated function I'm not sure if it uniformly converges on those bounds and thus if it is legal or not...

I also tried using the Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality on $\int_{\text{Left}}f(z)\text{ d}z=\int^{0}_{2\pi-\epsilon}\frac{(iy)^n}{e^{iy}-1}i\text{ d}y$ where
$$\left|\int^{0}_{2\pi}\frac{(iy)^n}{e^{iy}-1}i\text{ d}y\right|\le \int^{0}_{2\pi-\epsilon}\frac{\left|i^n\right|\left|y^n\right|}{\left|e^{iy}-1\right|}|i|\text{ d}y = \int^{0}_{2\pi-\epsilon}\frac{y^n}{\left|e^{iy}-1\right|}\text{ d}y\le \int^{0}_{2\pi-\epsilon}\frac{y^n}{\left|\left|e^{iy}\right|-\left|1\right|\right|}\text{ d}y$$
where the last part follows from $\frac{1}{|a-b|}\le\frac{1}{||a|-|b||}$ but this makes the denominator $0$ which is illegal so I probably did something wrong here.

So in the end, I would have the following equation: $$I-\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{(2\pi i+x)^n}{e^x-1}\text{ d}x - \int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{(iy)^n}{e^{iy}-1}i\text{ d}y=2^{n-1} (i\pi)^{n+1}$$

And... I'm stuck. If anyone can help it would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: You've overloaded $n$ as you use it in two different contexts:  $x^n$ (or $z^n$) and $z=2 \pi i n$. Isn't $\int\limits_{\mathcal{C}} f(z)\,dz=\int\limits_0^R+\int\limits_R^{R+\pi i}+\int\limits_{R+\pi i}^{\pi i}+\int\limits_ {\pi i}^{0} f(z)\,dz=0$ also valid and simpler?

Comment: @StevenClark fixed the n thing. Also if I chose that contour, nothing would really change Save for one less integral and slightly different bounds. I’m still lost as to how to do some integrals along the contour.

Comment: @metamorphy I don’t quite get what you mean. If the general case will not work, perhaps instead of a general $n$ we can choose a particular value of $n$? Perhaps the $n=1$ or $n=2$?

Comment: @metamorphy plus this expression shouldn’t be specific to zeta? For any arbitrary $n$ we could express the antiderivative in terms of polylogarithm functions.

Comment: Note for future readers that I had a misconception of the cauchy schwartz inequality here. What i refer to as the CSI is actually the triangle inequality for integerals^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completed my investigation a while back (like half a year ago ish) but I never gave this question closure, so I might as well do it now to help anyone who may come across this.

---

*This integral is impossible to evaluate using contour integration.*

Doing so would mean we would have a closed form for the zeta function at odd integers.

---

The original motivation was to attempt to evaluate the series definition of the Riemann Zeta function. In particular, I noticed how this approach worked on evaluating $S=\zeta(2)=\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

This was done by inverse Laplace transforming the summand or by noticing that
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{x\right\}(n)=\frac{1}{n^2}=\int^{\infty}_{0}xe^{-nx}\text{ d}x,\qquad n>0$$

This was substituted into the integral to obtain
\begin{align}
    S&=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\int^{\infty}_{0}xe^{-nx}\text{ d}x\\
    &=\int^{\infty}_{0}x\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}e^{-nx}\text{ d}x\\
    &=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{x\text{ d}x}{e^x-1}
\end{align}

By using $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{e^z-1}$ (*this "one more power" thing is the same as the trick used to evaluate integrals with logs in the numerator*) and the same contour shown in the question, the contour integral collapses into $$\oint_{\mathcal{C}}f(z)\text{ d}z=-4\pi iI+\int^{\infty}_0\frac{2\pi^2\text{ d}x}{e^x-1}+2i\pi^3+\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{iy^2\text{ d}y}{e^{iy}-1}=0$$

**The key aspect to note is that the two unsolved integrals that remain are divergent**, and will actually cancel each other out if we take a principal value "over" the two integrals, but we do not need to deal with them. Instead, can pass the equation through the imaginary part function and equate the results, which give
$$-4\pi I+2\pi^3+\int^{2\pi}_0\Im\left(\frac{iy^2}{e^{iy}-1}\right)\text{ d}y=0$$
Separating real and imaginary parts of the integrand of the last integral gives us
$$-4\pi I+2\pi^3+\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{-y^2\text{ d}y}{2}=0$$
$$S=\frac{-2\pi^3+\frac{4}{3}\pi^3}{-4\pi}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

---

I was hence intruiged in the case of the generalized integral

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}\text{ d}x,\qquad n>0,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Of course, this could always simplify it back down to a series, where we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^m}{e^x-1}\text{ d}x &= \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}x^m}{1-e^{-x}}\text{ d}x\\ &=\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^me^{-x(n+1)}\text{ d}x\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}x^me^{-x(n+1)}\text{ d}x\\ &=\Gamma(m+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{m+1}}\\ &=\boxed{\Gamma(m+1)\zeta(m+1)}
\end{align}

Regardless, if we approach this using contour integration with a $f(z)=\frac{z^{n+1}}{e^z-1}$.

We see the problem when we evaluate the integral along the left side of the contour integral, which gives us $$\int^{0}_{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}y^{n+1}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}-\frac y2\right)\csc\left(\frac y2\right)\text{ d}y$$

Plugging in an even $n$ (hence evaluating the zeta function at odd $n$) makes this integral divergent.

Now, if we look at the integrals along the top and bottom parts of the contour, when we pass the imaginary part function through them, we'd get the even powered numerators, which would also contain a divergent integral.

The slew of divergent integrals would in a sense "combine" and cancel out to give a finite value, but there's really no way of calculating this. Hence the integral is unable to be calculated.

In the prior example with $\zeta(2)$, the divergent parts were removed by the imaginary part function, but in the general case and cases of odd input for the zeta function, this divergence is a big problem that contour integration just can't solve.